# Enforce referential integrity on subset of field values

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is enforcing referential integrity on subset of field values possible in Oracle (>11g)?

For example, function based referential integrity like function based indexes.
Or referential integrity only on one specific partition of a table.

For example, I have a `history_value_table (varname VARCHAR2(30), value VARCHAR2(100))` table.

I only want to enforce referential integrity on `value` where `varname = 'TEST'`.

So if I would partition the table based on `varname`, a referential integrity constraint would only be put on the partition where `varname = 'TEST'`. Or if function based referential integrity was possible, then it would be based on something like this: `CASE WHEN varname = 'TEST' THEN value ELSE '-1' END`.

Comment: What do you want? Show us examples of inputs and outpus

Comment: @zaratustra Example added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a virtual column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE ... ADD value_UC VARCHAR2(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
(CASE varname WHEN 'TEST' THEN varname ELSE NULL END);
```

Then you can create a unique constraint on that column and use it for referential integrity.
Note the `ELSE NULL`, `ELSE '1'` does not work

Comment: I can create the referential integrity constraint like this: `ALTER TABLE history_value_table ADD CONSTRAINT TEST FOREIGN KEY ( value_UC ) REFERENCES TEST (TEST);` But once I add the index the DB gives me `ORA-03113` when inserting. It appears that the `GENERATE ALWAYS` actualy makes an index and uses this index for the column?

Comment: Creating a referential integrity requires an unique constraint (i.e. als an unique index) on parent table. It should not be possible to create it without having the index created before.